# JQuery custom function on form submit - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a custom function that I am trying to use in a JQuery Mobile hybrid app. When a form is submitted, instead of the default handler, I would like my function to be triggered.

I have the following form:

```
<form id="frmFillup">
        <label for="odReading">Total Odometer Reading:</label>
        <input type="number" data-clear-btn="true"
            name="odReading" id="odReading" value="1">

        <label for="fuelReading">Total Fuel:</label>
        <input type="number" data-clear-btn="true"
            name="fuelReading" id="fuelReading" value="1">

        <label for="totalPrice">Total Price:</label>
        <input type="number" data-clear-btn="true"
            name="totalPrice" id="totalPrice" value="1">

        <label for="stationAddress">Station address:</label>
        <textarea
            name="stationAddress" id="stationAddress">1 main st</textarea>

        <button data-theme="a" name="saveFillup" id="saveFillup">Save Fillup</button>
    </form>
```

and I install a listener at the top of my HTML page:

```
    $('#frmFillup').submit(
        function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                alert('Saving!!');
                saveFillup();
        }
    );
```

However, it looks like the default submit function is still firing, and my custom function never gets fired (nor do I get the alert box in my custom event listener). Chrome dev tools don't show any javascript errors in the console -- it looks like it's just not binding the submit handler. Any & all help is very much appreciated!

The full code is on github at https://github.com/cristoslc/petrolog/blob/master/www/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your event might not have attached to the button. Try wrapping code inside document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#frmFillup').submit(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         alert('Saving!!');
         saveFillup();
     });
});
```

The default type of button is not "submit" in IE 7 and below. So you should consider adding type="submit" to the button to make sure it works fine in all the browsers.

```
<button type="submit" data-theme="a" name="saveFillup" id="saveFillup">Save Fillup</button>
```

Comment: If you use a button but don't use the type attribute, the default value is "submit".

Comment: @HolgerThiebosch Not for IE7 and below.

Comment: I checked in IE9. My mistake. ;-)

Comment: @rakhi4110 Thanks, wrapping it at document ready was exactly the missing step. Also, thanks for the heads-up for older cross-browser compatibility -- I'm sure that would have had me tearing at my hair when I got there :-)

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
 $('#saveFillup').click(function () {
  //your code here
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

just add:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#frmFillup').submit(
        function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            console.log('submit catched: ', e);
        }
    );
});
```

I've tested it, IE, FF, Chrome
When a button doesn't have a type= its by default submit. so that works. The form gets an submit event.